# Android MD5 hash from contentresolver inputstream

Tags: android, md5

I'm trying to upload a file from my android app to my server, and to be sure it is done correctly I would like to add the MD5 hash. The file to be uploaded is referenced by a content:// Uri. I use the below code to calculate the MD5 hash on my android device, and a slightly different code on my server (see comment in code). Now the problem is that these 2 don't give the same result. I've used some third-party software and the MD5 hash on my server is actually correct. How do I solve this?

```
public static String calculateMD5(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
    MessageDigest digest;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while getting digest", e);
        return null;
    }

    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
        // is = new FileInputStream("some_file_location");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while getting FileInputStream", e);
        return null;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    try {
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aMessageDigest : md5sum) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception on closing MD5 input stream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get hash value

```
private String getFIleHashValue(File updateFile) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("calculateMD5", "Exception while getting Digest", e);
            return "";
        }

        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(updateFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("calculateMD5", "Exception while getting FileInputStream", e);
            return "";
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read;
        try {
            while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
            String output = bigInt.toString(16);
            // Fill to 32 chars
            output = String.format("%32s", output).replace(' ', '0');
            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("calculateMD5", "Exception on closing MD5 input stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
```